# noClassDefFoundException in javafx application in raspberry pi

Tags: java, linux

I'm new to raspberry api, i have created a javaFX application from windows 7 using netbeans 7.3.1 , jdk 1.7 .. database used is firebird .. so i incorporated jaybird jar with library 
after that i clean and build the application.. then copied the dist folder to raspberrypi 
machine.

Then i tried to run the jar from command line ..
but it gives Exception like `"noClassDefFoundError:org/firebirdsql/even/EventManager` " and exiting the application..

But it works fine with windows 7,ubuntu and centOS

Why I have the above exception when I start my javafx application in raspberry pi only.Can anyone give any help

thanks...

Comment: Did you add the jaybird jar to your classpath?

Comment: how to add jaybird jar to classpath ??

Comment: sorry , am not aware of that

Comment: I am not well verse with raspberry pi. Although a NoClassDefFoundError specifies that a particular class was present at compile time but missing at runtime. You can further understand it here - http://javareferencegv.blogspot.com/2013/10/debugging-javalangnoclassdeffounderror.html

Comment: i have added jaybird jar in classpath but it doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to configure Buildpath of your project and add jaybird jar. Do this as suggested below:

```
RightClick on your Project -> Build Path -> Configure Buildpath
```

Then the window be will be shown with Libraries as one of the tab. Select that tab.

Then click `Add External Jars` in the right side buttons list. Add the required Jars and `select OK`. Once clean and build your project.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: sorry , i cant find any build path option while right click on my project